# sbt dependsOn, typesafe config merges application.conf

Tags: dependencies, sbt, typesafe-config

I have a project with two modules, `A` and `B`. Each has an `application.conf` and a `local.conf` that includes the former. My project's `build.sbt` file specifies:

```
B.dependsOn(A % "compile->compile")
```

It appears that the `local.conf` for module `B` is including `application.conf` for module `A`, because I am getting an `UnresolvedSubstitution` exception for substituted values in module `A`'s `application.conf` when trying to run module `B`.

I think it is merging the `application.conf` files. Is there any way to stop it doing this? In particular, can I do it via the `build.sbt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
B.dependsOn(A % "compile->compile")
```

what happens is that when `B` is compiled, it executes `A` compilation and makes it available to `B`. This means your configuration files in `A` will be available to `B` because Type-Safe configuration puts those configurations into the classpath.

The easiest solution is probably to namespace your properties so that module `B` is only using properties from it's own configuration and never `A`s. (This is a best practice, to keep separation of concerns clear.) If the intent is for `B`'s configuration to *override* `A`'s 'default' configuration, and assuming `A` is essentially a library being used by `B`, following the [best practice guideline here](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior) and place a `resource.conf` file in `A` and an `application.conf` file in `B`, since `application.conf` is higher-priority.

In your case, both `A` and `B` rely on common code. In order to preserve separation of concerns, it is best to refactor this common code into it's own library module and have *both* `A` and `B` reference that code. In this manner you can ensure that the properties they both rely on are in `C` and properties that are properly set by either `A` or `B` are in their domain alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, in practise A and B are both applications, not libraries, but A happens to have a clasd that I want in B already coded, so I thought I'd import it to reduce code duplication, and thus the dependency. So, what exactly do you mean by namespacing? Will it help in this situation?

Comment: It is common to, if there are two applications that reference similar classes, to move those classes into a library module both applications can call. Namespacing refers to putting a prefix on your property, so it's clear where it is. For instance, the names space of `java.util.List` is is `java.util`, so that it's not confused with `com.mystuff.shopping.List`. In this case you can do `A.someproperty` and `B.someproperty`.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, I think the common library solution is optimal and I will use that. Should I mark the above post as my solution, or should one of us create a new one?

Comment: @Logician Done! Sorry to take so long; was mobile.